# can't create List for sharepoint using C# sample via graph API

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Refer to Graph API v1.0 doc -> [Create List section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

I add below C# example in my code to create List：

`var list = new List`
`{`
`DisplayName = "Books",`
`Columns = new List<ColumnDefinition>()`
    `{`
        `new ColumnDefinition`
        `{`
            `Name = "Author",`
            `Text = new TextColumn`
            `{`
            `}`
        `},`
        `new ColumnDefinition`
        `enter code here`{
            `Name = "PageCount",`
            `Number = new NumberColumn`
            `{`
            `}`
        `}`
    `},`

```
`List = new ListInfo`
`{`
    `Template = "genericList"`
`}`
```

`};`

`await graphClient.Sites["{site-id}"].Lists.Request().AddAsync(list);`

but get below errors:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'Microsoft.Graph.IListColumnsCollectionPage'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/656Wf.png)

What should be the correct C# to create List via graph API?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested code based on [this project](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-csharp-connect-sample).

```
var graphServiceClient = GraphClientFactory.GetGraphServiceClient(config.ClientId, config.Authority, config.Scopes);

            if (graphServiceClient != null)
            {                    
                List<ColumnDefinition> listOfCols = new List<ColumnDefinition>() {
                    new ColumnDefinition
                        {
                            Name = "Author",
                            Text = new TextColumn
                            {
                            }
                        },
                        new ColumnDefinition
                        {
                            Name = "PageCount",
                            Number = new NumberColumn
                            {
                            }
                        }
                };

                ListColumnsCollectionPage columns = new ListColumnsCollectionPage();
                foreach (ColumnDefinition item in listOfCols)
                {
                    columns.Add(item);
                }

                List list = new List
                {
                    DisplayName = "TestGraph",
                    Columns = columns,
                    ListInfo = new ListInfo
                    {
                        Template = "genericList"
                    }
                };

                await graphServiceClient.Sites["tenant.sharepoint.com,x-b669-4537-b0f5-x,x-e306-407b-b1a2-x"].Lists
                    .Request()
                    .AddAsync(list);
                Console.WriteLine("----");
            }
```

[image]

Comment: You could accept it as answer so it would help others.